# Why are operations (in groups or algebras) always ordered in a one-dimensional way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Take rotations in 3D as a toy example. The ordering of the transformations obviously matters because they don't commute. This reflects the physical fact that one rotation happens *after* another in the real world.

**Why is mathematics so tied to the maxim "One operation happens after the other"?**

Other thoughts: Why is there no example (that I know of) where objects or operations are stacked or applied in multiple directions? Think of an array. Think of multiplying from above and below instead of just left and right.

Comment: [Planar algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra?wprov=sfti1)?

Comment: There's also the ["visual" Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann–Hilton_argument#Two-dimensional_proof).

Comment: 2-categories, Penrose notation, tensor networks, diagrammatic calculus